# Adding to PlayPrefs is Inconsistent Unity Ads

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to add coins to my PlayerPrefs after watching an Ad, but the first Reward is 100 coins and then it's getting way more and inconsisten.
I have no Idea why this problem is occuring.
Thanks

```
public void OnUnityAdsShowComplete(string adUnitId, UnityAdsShowCompletionState showCompletionState)
        {
            float coins = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("coinPrefs");
            if (adUnitId.Equals(_adUnitId) && showCompletionState.Equals(UnityAdsShowCompletionState.COMPLETED))
            {
                Debug.Log("Unity Ads Rewarded Ad Completed");
                // Grant a reward.
                PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("coinPrefs", coins + 100);
                // Load another ad:
                Advertisement.Load(_adUnitId, this);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Debug.Log("Unity Ads Rewarded Ad Completed");
                // Grant a reward.
                PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("coinPrefs",PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("coinPrefs")+100);
                // Load another ad:
                Advertisement.Load(_adUnitId, this);
```

And If your number of coins is whole number it is better to set it as int